# Looping a regression in VBA

Tags: vba, loops, regression

I have a worksheet with my x data set staying the same and I want to run 100 different regressions, using different y data-sets.

The code I have is

```
 Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range("$F$3:$F$22"), _
 ActiveSheet.Range("$C$3:$E$22"), False, False, , Range("F2").Value, False, False, _
 False, False, , False
```

How can i loop this so that the y data set will change to the next column, in this case G3:G22 and also name the worksheet by what the header is this case it would be cell G2?

Thank you

Comment: You should format your code when you post. Take a look here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
Dim x as WorkSheet : Set x = ActiveSheet '<-- I'd recommend to set it with the sheet's name (i.e. x = Worksheets("Xdataset"))
Dim col as string
For Each col In Array("F", "G") '<-- setup the columns you want to iterate on
    Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", x.Range(col & "3:" & col & "22"), _
    x.Range("$C$3:$E$22"), False, False, , x.Range(col & "2").Value, False, False, _
    False, False, , False
Next
```

EDIT

Since you need to go as far as to `CU`, the array solution may become difficult to type. A better solution for this case would be:

```
Dim x as WorkSheet : Set x = ActiveSheet '<-- I'd recommend to set it with the sheet's name (i.e. x = Worksheets("Xdataset"))
Dim col as Range
For Each col in x.Range("F3:CU22").Columns
    Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", col, 
    x.Range("$C$3:$E$22"), False, False, , col.Cells(0).Value, False, False, False, False, , False
Next
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to work, am i able to setup those columns in the array by doing a range like Array("G:O"), or do i need to individually type out the columns?

Comment: @user7340640 with this solution you need to fill the array explicitly, i.e. `Array("F", "G", "H", ..., "O")`. We can make it automatic as well but I dont think it is worth it, it is just about filling the array :)

Comment: I see. The only reason I ask is because I need this to go all the way to column "CU".

Comment: I appreciate all the help though, this saved me lots of time

Comment: Ah, if you need to go to CU, indeed we need to do better, because you might make typos and the code becomes difficult to read. I will add another solution.

Comment: @user7340640 Please see the new version it should better suit this case.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much!